# z3 reports unknown for decidable fragment with proof-production enabled

Tags: z3

We have a (large) SMT-LIBv2 input file, using the `QF_UF`logic fragment. Z3 is able to determine that the file is `unsat` in a few seconds. However, when we turn on proof-production, z3 reports `unknown` after just a few seconds and without using significant memory resources. When trying the same file with a different solver (veriT), we are able to obtain a proof (~500 KB) in just a few seconds.

As `QF_UF` is a decidable fragment, and also our file does not seem too difficult, we are rather surprised by this result. Our best guess is that z3 exhausts some sort of internal resource limit. So we have two questions: Is there a way to find out why z3 gives up and reports `unknown` (so quickly)? And if this is due to some internal limit, can this be increased by some configuration setting?

Comment: It is hard to explain without seeing the benchmark.

Comment: I sent you the benchmarks in question by email.